# Get rid of the "Your conversation is all set up" message

Tags: skype

In Skype, during every call there is this incredibly annoying message that permanently sits on the right hand side:

[image]

Every 2 seconds the face smiles, blinks and waves. It's insanely obnoxious.

Is there any way to get rid of it? (Or at least stop the animation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooray, there is a way. In Preferences > Messaging, set "Emoticons" to "Don't show".

[image]

Now it looks like this:

[image]

There is also "Standard" which prevents the animations.